# Unity: Improvements to skinnedMeshRender.BakeMesh performance or alternatives?

Tags: unity, mesh, skinning

I'm running to a situation where I need to do some manual deformation to a skinnedMeshRenderer's mesh vertices after applying some blendskinning. I'm finding that the following code takes ~15ms to run. I've calculated the time both by running it 100 times and measuring time difference, and by using the Unity Profiler.

```
Mesh bakedMesh = new Mesh();
skinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh(bakedMesh);
```

The mesh has ~7000 vertices.

I just need loop through each vertex to get its current (blendskinned) position relative to its gameObject's local origin. The goal is to calculate the amount of deformation it experienced.

so something like (pseudocode):

```
for i in vertices
    deformation[i] = originalVerticies[i] - bakedCertices[i]
```

It's the call to `BakeMesh` that is slowing things down, which is required to get `bakedVertices[i]`.

Is there another way to get backedVerticies[i] without actually baking the mesh? Maybe some kind of manual calculation to simulate baking but only on the vertices? or perhaps some way to speed up the baking process?

---

**Additional info:**

The reason i'm calculating the deformation is to undo unity's automatic linear blend skinning, since at runtime I want to move some bones without affecting the mesh. However, when I move the bones, unity's automatic linear blend skinning kicks in and deforms the mesh, so this is a way to calculate how much it was deformed so I can "Undo" this blend skinnning by adding the deformation back on to the vertices. Perhaps there is a more elegant solution, but I can't find any way to temporarily turn off the automatic linear blend skinning. Note that I need to do this every single frame.

I'm currently at 15ms for this script, which is really pushing the 16ms limit to maintain 60fps. When I add other scripts etc into the scene it will for sure be laggy. I would also like it to run at at least 90fps since i hope to use this script in VR in the future.

Comment: Why do you want to move bones without the mesh moving with them? What end goal or effect is this serving? There may be more efficient routes to that effect.

Comment: I'm using a scientific package of body models where the mesh and bones don't quite line up. I have a correction algorithm for how to re-position the bone locations. But when I apply this, the mesh deforms automatically, since the bones moved. Currently i'm "undoing this" by reversing this deformation by baking the mesh, calculating how much it deformed, then adding this back to the mesh.

Comment: Sounds like something that could more efficiently be fixed in your source asset, in less development time.

Comment: Yeah, that's something i am worried about. I don't have access to the the source. I guess I'll try contacting them, or find some way to do this baking manually

Comment: You could read your mesh at edit time, and bake out one improved version with corrected bones & weights, then use your fixed version at runtime. To advise as to how to do this though, we'd need to see the specific errors we need to correct.

Comment: The bones can be potentially modified every frame with basically infinite permutations, so pre-computing them is not possible. It's how they structured their assets unfortunately. Rather than the mesh being calculated from the bones, it's the other way around. Which does not play well with unity.

Comment: I'd reiterate then that it sounds like it would *really* help to show us what specific effect you're creating with this unusual bone setup. Without exposure to your specific situation, I honestly can't fathom what you could be doing that would demand such a setup. I very strongly suspect there's a simpler solution, but since I haven't seen the problem I can't provide any further guidance.